# Updating iOS 3 app to iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios4

I get a SIGABRT on this line:

```
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

This worked fine in iOS 3.2, but it's broken now.

Why doesn't this work anymore?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about the error? I am assuming this is in your Appdelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

instead.